# Как преобразовать один многоугольник в другой, используя только параллельный перенос и пропорциональное масштабирование?

Tags: python, алгоритм, вычислительная-геометрия

На входе даны два многоугольника (перечислены координаты вершин этих многоугольников в порядке их обхода; однако, порядок обхода для разных многоугольников может быть выбран разный). Можно ли преобразовать один многоугольник в другой, используя только параллельный перенос и пропорциональное масштабирование?

Comment: Ещё вариант: для каждого многоугольника построить список элементов вида `[..., [L_i, theta_i], ...]`, где `L_i` -- длина `i`-го ребра, `theta_i` -- угол поворота следующего (`i+1`-го) ребра относительно этого (`i`-го). После того списки (с точностю до циклической перестановки или другим образом, смотря как изменён порядок обхода) сравнить: углы должны быть одинаковы, а отношение длин рёбер постоянно для всех сравнений.

Comment: [Этот же вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56261926/) на буржуйском SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Найти какую-то вершину, предположительно общую для обоих многоугольников(максимум или минимум по координатам)

Сделать перенос одного многоугольника, чтобы эти вершины лежали на одной точке

Сделать масштабирование, чтобы соседняя точка совпала с соответствующей точкой другого многоугольника

Проверить совпадают ли остальные точки. Если совпадают - можно, нет - нельзя

Comment: Хорошо что в задачке не сказано про поворот )